# django rest framework deserialize object based on custom class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I would like to deserialize this json:

```
json1 = {
    "age" : "22",
    "name" : "Bob",
    "lastname" : "Andrew",
    "contactList" : [
    { "friend" : "Alice"},
    {  "friend" : "John"}
]}
```

I have created the following classes (I dont want to create any models since I am no interested in saving them in the database):

```
class Friend(object):
    def __init__(self, friend):
        self.friend = friend

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, age , name , lastname, contactList):
        self.age=age
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.contactList= []   #possible error here
```

and the following serializers:

```
class FriendSeriliazer(serializers.Serializer):
    friend = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Friend(**validated_data)

class PersonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    age = serializers.CharField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    lastname = serializers.CharField()
    contactList = FriendSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
         print validated_data
         simple = Person(**validated_data)
         contactList = self.validated_data.pop('contactList')
         for friend in contactList:
             serializer = FriendSerializert(data=friend)
             if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                person.contactList.append(serializer.save())
         return person
```

The POST method from the view:

```
    parsedData = PersonSerializer(data=request.data)
    person = parsedData.save()
    print person.contactList[0].friend #<-- nested object should be present  
    return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I used the drf [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) for this

The problem is that while this works I need to deserialize a much more complex json and iterating the inner objects in the create function isn't gonna cut it. Is there a more automated way?

Comment: why implement a `create` method if you don't want  to save them?

Comment: I started without one but then I got an exception `NotImplementedError: create() must be implemented`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you don't want to save in database but in an object and **Django-Rest-Framework doesn't support writable nested serializers by default**, then there is no other better solution than what you are doing. You have to implement this process by yourself.

> By default nested serializers are read-only. If you want to support
>   write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create
>   `create()` and/or `update()` methods in order to explicitly specify how
>   the child relationships should be saved.

Read Django-Rest-Framework documentation for more information : [Writable nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: I actually want to save the data from the json to an object type of Person class, without saving it to the database. Thats why I have only implemented the Person and Friend Classes and not their Models.
Based on your code: 

          `object = serializer.validated_data`

the returned Object is of type dict and I want the returned object to be of type Person